# Validation Error message on VF page

Tags: visualforce

Can anyone tell me how to hide the first system error message in Visualforce page?. I have attached an Image.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257999/capture-only-the-error-message-from-validation-rule-and-display-in-vf-page

Comment: Check above link...

Comment: do want to hide first page message ? then I suggest use try catch in your controller and catch the exception and add into apexPages. like above link shared by Mohith.